# multi node cassandra installation ended with "UnknownHostException"

Tags: cassandra

I am newbie to Cassandra. I wanted to install cassandra-0.8.4 on 3 nodes and to run Map/Reduce job that uploads data from HDFS to Cassandra.

I have installed Cassnadra on 3 nodes lab02(199.168.0.2),lab03(199.168.0.3) & lab04(199.168.0.4) respectively and can create a keyspace & column family and they got distributed across the cluster.

When I run my map/reduce program it ended up with "UnknownHostException". the same map/reduce program works well on single node cluster.

Here are the steps which I have followed.

1. cassandra.yaml details

> lab02(199.168.0.2): (seed node)
>
> auto_bootstrap: false seeds: "199.168.0.2" listen_address: 199.168.0.2
>   rpc_address: 199.168.0.2
>
> lab03(199.168.0.3): auto_bootstrap: true seeds: "199.168.0.2"
>   listen_address: 199.168.0.3 rpc_address: 199.168.0.3
>
> lab04(199.168.0.4): auto_bootstrap: true seeds: "199.168.0.2"
>   listen_address: 199.168.0.4 rpc_address: 199.168.0.4

2.
When I run my map/reduce program it ended up with "UnknownHostException"

Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: /199.168.0.2 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849) at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1200) at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153) at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083) at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019) at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:969) at org.apache.cassandra.client.RingCache.refreshEndpointMap(RingCache.java:93) at org.apache.cassandra.client.RingCache.(RingCache.java:67) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:98) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:92) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.java:132) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.java:62) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:553) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:408) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)

Here are the config line for map/reduce.

```
    job4.setReducerClass(TblUploadReducer.class );
    job4.setOutputKeyClass(ByteBuffer.class);
    job4.setOutputValueClass(List.class);
    job4.setOutputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.class);
    ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job4.getConfiguration(), args[1],args[3] );
    ConfigHelper.setRpcPort(job4.getConfiguration(),  args[7]); // 9160
    ConfigHelper.setInitialAddress(job4.getConfiguration(), args[9]); // 199.168.0.2
    ConfigHelper.setPartitioner(job4.getConfiguration(), "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");
```

Steps which I have verified are

- There is a passwordless ssh has been configured b/w lab02,lab03
  &lab04. All the nodes can ping each other with out any issues.
- When I ran "InetAddress.getLocalHost()" from java program on lab02 it
  prints "lab02/199.168.0.2".
- When I over looked "o/p" of bin/cassandra it prints couple of
  messages and under InetAddress field "/199.168.0.3" etc. Here it does
  not print "hostname/IP". Is that problem?

Kindly help me to resolve above issue.

Regards,
Thamizhannal

Answer (score 3):

This has been resolved already in 0.8 tip: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3044

Comment: Above URL looks it has been bug reported on Cassandra-0.8.4 and has been fixed on version 0.8.5. So, either I have wait till 0.8.5 release Or else I have to move to 0.7.8.

Comment: Or check out the 0.8 branch from svn.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to look up the literal string "/199.168.0.2" as an address, which is indeed invalid.  If this is coming from your configuration, remove the slash.  Otherwise, it might be coming from RingCache which would be a bug.  If so, first upgrade to 0.7.8 to make sure it's not already fixed.  If the problem persists, open a bug on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA.

Edit: Nate is right, this is a known bug in 0.8.4 that is fixed for 0.8.5.